# Java Web Service return null after save in database

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, rest

I have the following problem. This is my web service:

**I get id and name oficina:**

```
@GET
    @Path("oficinas/{idEmpresa}")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public List<Oficinas> listaOficinas(@PathParam("idEmpresa") String idEmpresa) {
        int numReg;
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT ID_OFICINA, NOMBRE_OFICINA FROM OFICINAS WHERE ID_OFICINA =\""+idEmpresa+"\"", Oficinas.class);
        numReg = query.getResultList().size();
        if(numReg > 2) {
            numReg -= 2;
        } else {
            numReg = 0;
        }
        query.setFirstResult(numReg);
        return (List<Oficinas>) query.getResultList();
    }
```

**This gets the full name of the staff according to office:**

```
@GET
    @Path("personalLaborando/{idOficina}")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public List<Personal> personalLaborando(@PathParam("idOficina") String idOficina) {
        int numReg;
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT ID_PERSONAL, NOMBRE, APELLIDO_PATERNO, APELLIDO_MATERNO "
                + "FROM PERSONAL WHERE ID_OFICINA = \""+idOficina+"\"", Personal.class);
        numReg = query.getResultList().size();
        if(numReg > 100 ) {
            numReg -= 100;
        }else {
            numReg = 0;
        }
        query.setFirstResult(numReg);
        return (List<Personal>) query.getResultList();
    }
```

**And this code for getting the categories:**

```
@GET
    @Path("categorias")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public List<Categoria> listaCategoria() {
        int numReg;
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT *FROM CATEGORIA", Categoria.class);
        numReg = query.getResultList().size();
        if(numReg > 10) {
            numReg -= 10;
        } else {
            numReg = 0;
        }
        query.setFirstResult(numReg);
        return (List<Categoria>) query.getResultList();
    }
```

**My Json categories before the save:**

```
[{"descripcion":"MOBILIARIO","idCategoria":1},{"descripcion":"PAPELERIA","idCategoria":2},{"descripcion":"ELECTRONICA","idCategoria":3},{"descripcion":"LIMPIEZA","idCategoria":4},{"descripcion":"OTRO","idCategoria":5}]
```

Office:

```
[{"idOficina":22,"nombreOficina":"ORFIS SUR"}]
```

Personal:

```
[{"apellidoMaterno":"karla","apellidoPaterno":"karla","idPersonal":2,"nombre":"Karla"},{"apellidoMaterno":"Lopez","apellidoPaterno":"Lopez","idPersonal":3,"nombre":"Juan"},{"apellidoMaterno":"Jimenez","apellidoPaterno":"Lopez","idPersonal":8,"nombre":"Rico"}]
```

**After save:**

Categories:

```
[{"descripcion":"MOBILIARIO","idCategoria":1},{"descripcion":"PAPELERIA","idCategoria":2},{"descripcion":"ELECTRONICA","idCategoria":3},{"idCategoria":4},{"descripcion":"OTRO","idCategoria":5}]
```

Office:

```
[{"idOficina":22}]
```

Personal:

```
[{"apellidoMaterno":"karla","apellidoPaterno":"karla","idPersonal":2,"nombre":"Karla"},{"apellidoMaterno":"Lopez","apellidoPaterno":"Lopez","idPersonal":3,"nombre":"Juan"},{"idPersonal":8}]
```

All right, this works fine when the client loads the data into a spinner and choose what he wants, but after sending the data and keep wanting to select the office and staff I get null values.

What is my mistake ?
How could I fix that ?

Comment: Rephrased the question

Comment: How to get the full values ​​and not null fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only add next code line after
 em.persist();

```
em.clean();
```

And ready!!